# Cannot open plugin manager jmeter 3.3

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to jmeter and I need to install some plugin.

For this I went to this site https://jmeter-plugins.org

and trying to install the plugin manager from option menu as written here: https://academy.blazemeter.com/lessons/lesson-3-variables-properties-functions/

but this is my option menu

[image]

why I am not seeing it on jmeter 3.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On first install you need to:

1. Download [latest plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) jar
2. Copy it to JMeter's lib/ext folder
3. Restart JMeter.

Check [Install](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/) page of jmeter-plugins:

> Download plugins-manager.jar and put it into lib/ext directory, then restart JMeter.